# Calling Win32 CreateEvent() fails from an IIS 7.5 web application

Tags: c++, winapi, interop, zeromq

I am working with a native library ([libzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq)), which is called by a C# wrapper ([clrzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq)). It is being used by an IIS web application (IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2, ASP.NET MVC 3).

The native library makes a call to [CreateEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but this fails when running the web application using the ApplicationPoolIdentity. It works if I use the LocalSystem account instead but I'd rather not do this.

I have tried both with and without the "Global\" prefix for the event name.

**Is there a way of giving the ApplicationPoolIdentity the required permissions?**

The relevant snippet of code is below:

```
//  Make the following critical section accessible to everyone.
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {0};
sa.nLength = sizeof (sa);
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
BOOL ok = InitializeSecurityDescriptor (&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
win_assert (ok);
ok = SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, (PACL) NULL, FALSE);
win_assert (ok);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = &sd;

//  This function has to be in a system-wide critical section so that
//  two instances of the library don't accidentally create signaler
//  crossing the process boundary.
HANDLE sync = CreateEvent (&sa, FALSE, TRUE,
    "Global\\zmq-signaler-port-sync");
win_assert (sync != NULL);
```

It fails on the last line, because sync is null.

For reference:

```
// Provides convenient way to check GetLastError-style errors on Windows.
#define win_assert(x) \
    do {\
        if (unlikely (!(x))) {\
            char errstr [256];\
            zmq::win_error (errstr, 256);\
            fprintf (stderr, "Assertion failed: %s (%s:%d)\n", errstr, \
                __FILE__, __LINE__);\
            zmq::zmq_abort (errstr);\
        }\
    } while (false)

#endif
```

Comment: Whats the error code? ( i suspect that your security attributes are incomparable with the address space that your module is loaded into (.Net environment)

Comment: I'm not getting an error code.

Comment: zmq eating the error code? if CreateEvent returns null I assure you sir there is indeed an error code.

Comment: How would I go about getting this error code? Ideally in the debugger.

Comment: DWORD ret = GetLastError(); Call it yourself.

Comment: The error code is 5, which I believe is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. I am currently running the website as NETWORK SERVICE, which has permissions to "Create glotal objects" according to the Local Security Policy MMC.

Comment: Yea, it's defiantly an security level issue. Is the library it's self running at NETWORK SERVICE though?

Comment: How would I check or modify this? I had assumed that an ASP.NET website calling a native library would mean the native library was running as the same user?

Comment: I forget(because I deal primarily with native and COM most of the time) what .NET run-time's default security descriptor is, but i do believe it's listed in the user accounts of the machine. How exactly have you wrapped that native lib? Is that native lib in a dynamic library or a static library?

Comment: I don't know about the descriptor either I'm afraid. The native library is dynamic (it's loaded from C:\Windows\System32)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has now been discussed and fixed:

- https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq/issues/81
- https://zeromq.jira.com/browse/LIBZMQ-335