# zeromq: "External component has thrown an exception" at the time of creation of new Context - on one particular system

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, zeromq

I am using 0mq with clr binding - version 3.2.2 - on Windows OS. On one particular Windows 7 64-bit system, 0mq always fails at the time of creation of a new Context. I initially thought it had something to do with windows services / IIS but it fails even for a simple console application

Error message below

```
Assertion failed: Connection timed out (..\..\..\signaler.cpp:260)
External component has thrown an exception.
```

Last error code (I am calling GetLastError from C#) is **10060** (which is connection tiemout)

Code below

```
var ctx = new Context(1);
```

I have checked the following links and tried the suggestions but no luck
http://grokbase.com/t/zeromq/zeromq-dev/126jmgg0aq/sehexception-when-calling-zmq-init-from-clrzmq
https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq/issues/81
[Calling Win32 CreateEvent() fails from an IIS 7.5 web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118493/calling-win32-createevent-fails-from-an-iis-7-5-web-application)

I have tried the following

- Used dependencychecker and ensured all referenced DLLs are present
- Ensured VC++ 2010 runtime is installed
- The account under which the console application ran has administrator privileges and I also gave explicit permissions to create global objects (one of the suggestions) in user account management

I am baffled by this bug. 0mq has worked great so far and I wanted to deploy it on a larger scale. Now this error is giving me second thoughts on the same. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your app isn't finding the appropriate ZMQ DLL.  A couple things to check:

1. Make sure that libzmq.dll is in the same directory as your exe.
2. Make sure that you know whether libzmq.dll is 32 or 64 bit.
3. Make sure that you've explicitly specified an architecture in your C# Project File (either x86 or x64, not AnyCPU), and that the architecture you pick matches the architecture of the libzmq.dll file you're using.

Comment: Thanx Scott. We have separate versions of libzmq and clrzmq for 32 and 64 bit and I am sure this was compiled with 64 bit (and all the 0mq modules are 64 bit). But will cross-check once again and update

Comment: Scott. I have checked everything related to 32 and 64 bit versions and the binaries are fine. It just fails on that system. The same code (both live and test app) works on all other systems (both 32 and 64 bit). Is there any other way to debug this issue?

Comment: When I answered, I didn't realize you were having the problem on one specific machine (as opposed to all 64 bit machines).  I don't have any other ideas for you, unfortunately.